# readline-like library for Java

Tags: java, console-application, readline, tab-completion, jline

Which readline-like library for Java do you use? By 'readline' like library I mean library for editing console input, with support for history, tab-completion, and stuff like this. I'm looking for one, and I cannot choose from so many choices ([jLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) -- unmaintained, [java-readline](http://java-readline.sourceforge.net/) -- last release on 2003, others?)

Comment: Should be community wiki

Comment: Community wiki police strikes again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used JLine to add history, etc. to a Clojure REPL (JVM process) when executed from the command line. It just magically worked and worked well, so I never bothered to investigate anything else.

Comment: Thank you for answer. jLine looks good except it is abandoned. I will give it a try and hope for not running into issues :)

Comment: It seems that Sonatype guys have custom version of JLine (http://github.com/jdillon/jline2)

Comment: jline3 is the successor to jline, and it is alive and well: https://github.com/jline/jline3

Answer (score 0):

jruby has an internal readline you could probably call out to.