# input BufferedReader how to terminate it

Tags: java, io

I have this piece of code

```
private String getMessage(BufferedReader in) throws IOException{

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     while(true){
        char pom = (char) in.read();
        sb.append(pom); 

        if (sb.toString().contains("\r\n")) {                  
               String result = sb.toString();
               result = result.replace("\r\n", "");
               return result;
        }
     }   
}
```

I want user to write on console some message. And when he writes '\r\n' console should end its input. But this doesn't work... Don't you have some tips what could be the problem?

And in aditional, i don't want to use in.close(); coz i will need this input later.

Comment: Have you debugged the program to see where it's failing?  What does "this doesn't work" mean?

Comment: well, i write and it does nothing. "qdio\r\ndosvp..." and can write still on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828291/readline-like-library-for-java might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private String getMessage(BufferedReader in) throws IOException{
    return in.readLine();
}
```

OK, if you want to do it byte by byte, then you can try this:

```
private String getMessage(BufferedReader in) throws IOException{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   char prev = (char) 0;
   char cur = in.read();
   while (prev != '\r' || cur != '\n') {
      sb.append(cur);
      prev = cur;
      cur = in.read();
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this would be great solution but because of some reasons I need to read informations byte by byte...

Comment: @user3472536, To read byte-by-byte you need an `InputStream`.  `Reader`s read chars, not bytes.

Comment: Same as my code. This is what i wrote on console and can write still on. http://d.pr/i/oNLu